# Processing Dataset in Batches using Webservices - C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have a c# web application which reads an excel file converts it to XML executes a stored procedure and returns a dataset in a specific format needed to execute a secondary update. The dataset returns 18000 plus records. Once the dataset has been populated I loop through and call a web-service to perform the update to the application database. My question is how could I go about performing this update in either smaller batches or smaller blocks or even using a progress bar. This is the function calling the web-service and running the update

```
public string InvokeSubmitCalendarValues()
{
    try
    {
        DataWebService dataWebService = new DataWebService();
        SubmitCalendarValuesRequest submitCalendarValuesRequest = new SubmitCalendarValuesRequest();
        Credentials credentials = new Credentials();

        credentials.Username = AmplaCodeUserName;
        credentials.Password = AmplaCodeUserPassword;
        credentials.Session = "";
        submitCalendarValuesRequest.Credentials = credentials;

        string rateUnit = "";

        if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    SubmitCalendarValue[] values = new SubmitCalendarValue[1];
                    SubmitCalendarValue values_ = new SubmitCalendarValue();

                    values_.Name = dr["ItemName"].ToString();
                    values_.Value = dr["ItemValue"].ToString();
                    // Init DateTime object value = 2017-08-06T00:00:00.0000000+02:00
                    // We going to use DateTime ctor that takes Ticks
                    values_.StartDateTime = new System.DateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ActiveDateTime"]).Ticks);

                    if (dr["PeriodType"].ToString() != string.Empty || !(dr["Period"] is DBNull))
                    {
                        CalendarRate rate = new CalendarRate();

                        rateUnit = dr["PeriodType"].ToString();
                        rate.Count = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Period"]);

                        CalendarRateUnit cru = (CalendarRateUnit)Enum.Parse(typeof(CalendarRateUnit), rateUnit);

                        rate.Unit = cru;
                        values_.Rate = rate;
                    }

                    values[0] = values_;
                    submitCalendarValuesRequest.Values = values;

                    SubmitCalendarValuesResponse submitCalendarValuesResult = dataWebService.SubmitCalendarValues(submitCalendarValuesRequest);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message.ToString();
    }

    return "Success";
}
```

Comment: I must also add that I had all this processed via the backend but had to change everything and use a web-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all these stuff in back-end thread and just pass it XML and call a thread and return message to end user.

or you can upload your XML to server and create a job that do batch process and you land user to processing view.

Comment: I can't unfortunately because this writes to another application database which performs a flush action and only then presents the newly uploaded information.

Comment: then you need to write a middle-ware utility that perform your desired result

Comment: Ok, here is another question how do you read say 20 rows of a dataset and then the next 20 rows, so on and so on?